# Not able to reload the dataTable using ajax.url.load() method at clientside processing

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm new to jQuery and just started experimenting on dataTables - client side processing.I know that for client-side processing of dataTables all the data needs to be fetched at once  from server, but I still need to fetch some data on an event trigger and reload the dataTable again with the new data fetched. What I'm doing is fetch a list of JSON data from server side via AJAX call on the change event of a dropdown box. The ajax response is fed to a html table and after the table is populated I set a dataTable for it. So each time I select a different entry in the dropdown I need to triger this ajax and reload the datatable if it already exists. This is what I've tried so far.

jQuery:

```
    $('#selectBoxID').bind('change', function( event ){

    var selectBoxValue =$('#selectBoxID').val();

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',        
            url: '/getTableData.spr', 
            cache: false,      
            dataType :"json",
                data: {"mySelect" : selectBoxValue}, //data sent to request page    

            success: function(response) {


                    jQuery.each(response, function(key, value)
                 {

                    oTable = oTable + populateRows(key, value, oRow);               

                }); 


            console.log("@Ajax sucess, oTable HTML content is :" + oTable);
            $('#htmlTableID').append(oTable);


            if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#htmlTableID' ) ) 
            {       
            console.log("dataTable already exist. HTML table content is:" + oTable);
            console.log(" $ datatable obj  :" + oTableJq);
            oTableJq.ajax.url('/getTableData.spr').load();
            console.log("table reloaded" + oTableJq);                   

             }else
            {

            oTableJq= $('#htmlTableID').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bLengthChange":false,
            "bInfo": true,
            "iDisplayLength":10
                }); 
            console.log("html  string :" + oTable);
            oTableJq = $('#htmlTableID').DataTable({ajax:"data.json"});
            console.log("table created first time" + oTableJq);

            }

        }, //end of success block

            error: (function(message)  { alert("Error in fetching the data.");
            alert("error message : " + message); }),     

            }); 
            //   alert(" end of ajax call");

            oTable = ""; oRow = ""; oTableJq = "";              


    }); //alert("end of  bind, dropdown change event") ; 

}); // end of ready function

function populateRows(key, value, oRow)          
    {          
        oRow = oRow + '<tr><td><a class="achor" href='+""+ '>' + key + '</a></td><td>' 
        + value.date+ </td><td>' + value.username + '</td><td>' + value.email + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' ;

        return oRow;

     }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="container1">       

                    <table id="htmlTableID">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th> <strong>DATE</strong></th>                             
                            <th> <strong>USERNAME  </strong></th> 
                            <th> <strong> EMAIL </strong></th> 

                         </tr>
                         </thead> 

                            <tbody id="TbodyId"></tbody>
                    </table>

            </div>
```

In this code just before the dataTable is loaded the first time I get the datatables.net/tn/3 warning message saying dataTable cannot be reinitilized. Also after I trigger the second ajax call by selecting another value in dropdown I get Ajax error message from dataTable datatables.net/tn/7. After this error I get the new data display in raw html format, dataTable will not have initialized. Is there anyway to reload the data into the dataTable even destroying the DT is fine, but I'm not able make that working either. What is that I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working after I emptied the entire dom elements associated with the DIV inside which the html table resides and then added the dom structure along with the new data after the ajax callback and initialized the dataTable again. Here's the jQuery code.

```
    $('#selectBoxID').bind('change', function( event ){

    oDivContent = '<table id="htmlTableID">' +
                    '<thead>' + 
             // table header in query string.

                    ' </thead> ' +

                        '<tbody id="TbodyId"></tbody>' +
               ' </table> ' ;



var selectBoxValue =$('#selectBoxID').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',        
        url: '/getTableData.spr', 
        cache: false,      
        dataType :"json",
        data: {"mySelect" : selectBoxValue}, //data sent to request page    
        success: function(response) {
             jQuery.each(response, function(key, value){

                oTable = oTable + populateRows(key, value, oRow);               
            }); 


        console.log("@Ajax sucess, oTable HTML content is :" + oTable);
        $('#htmlTableID').append(oTable);


        if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#htmlTableID' ) ) 
        {       
        //console.log("dataTable already exist. HTML table content is:" + oTable);
    //console.log(" $ datatable obj  :" + oTableJq);

    oTableJq.fcDestroy();
    oTableJq.empty();

    $('#container1').empty(); //the div inside whcih table structure lies
    $('#container1').append(oDivContent);   //addign the table 

    $('#htmlTableID').append(oTable); 

    //   console.log("html table text(): "          +$('#htmlTableID').text());                                     
        oTableQ = $('#htmlTableID').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bLengthChange":false,
            "bInfo": true,
            "iDisplayLength":10             
        });             


         }else
        {

        oTableJq= $('#htmlTableID').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bLengthChange":false,
        "bInfo": true,
        "iDisplayLength":10
            }); 

        }

    }, //end of success block

        error: (function(message)  { alert("Error in fetching the data.");
        alert("error message : " + message); }),     

        }); 
        //   alert(" end of ajax call");

        oTable = ""; oRow = ""; oTableJq = "";              


}); //alert("end of  bind, dropdown change event") ; 

    }); // end of ready function

    function populateRows(key, value, oRow)          
   {          
    oRow = oRow + '<tr><td><a class="achor" href='+""+ '>' + key + '</a></td><td>' 
    + value.date+ </td><td>' + value.username + '</td><td>' + value.email + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' ;

    return oRow;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
 "bDestroy" :true
```

to your datatable so that it knows to destroy the existing one in a recreate.

If that does not work for you then you can also just clear the data from the table and read your new array.

```
oTableJq.empty();
oTableJq.fnAddData(yourArray);
```

Comment: Tried, exactly same output as I've described in question. Setting bDestroy to true didn't have any effect on the dataTable it seems.

Comment: You can also try to empty the table and then add in the new array.  Answer updated.

Comment: nope. No luck yet! I disabled 'destroy=true' and 'ajax.url.load()' statements and put the '' oTableJq.empty();oTableJq.fnAddData(response) '' to the if condition but I hit another error saying the object 'oTableJq' doesn't support this method[empty()] or property.

Comment: both of those methods are valid.....using them both on a number of pages I have.   Can you put your code in a jsFiddle so that it can be more closely examined.